# JPA: One Table with Two different databases

Tags: java, sql, jpa, kundera

I want to store my table in two different databases, (for example: HyperSQL and MYSQL), but I can't duplicate table annotation like this:

```
@Entity(name="users")
@Table(name = "users", schema = "Users@HyperSQL_pu")
@Table(name = "users", schema = "Users@Mysql_pu")
public class UserEntitie implements Serializable {}
```

Have any idea, how can I do this without duplicating my bean class

Answer (score 3):

This is why some people have recommended not to put schema information into annotations. Use `orm.xml` to specify schema information (schema name, table name, column name etc), and have one `orm.xml` per datastore that the system is deployed to. Clearly this means one EntityManagerFactory per datastore; you cannot have one class persisted into multiple datastores with the same EntityManagerFactory

Using annotations you can only specify something once, and would have to manually edit java files to redeploy.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible to use orm.xml, because I'm working with kundera as a framework, not hibernate, look : https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/276

Comment: If your JPA provider is claiming to be JPA compliant (which they do) then it should support orm.xml. Since your provider seemingly does not support orm.xml (basic capabilities) then it should remove all statements about being JPA compliant (so it does not waste users time). Perhaps tell them this. JPA has had orm.xml since JPA 1!!

Comment: @BillyFrost why don't you tell us. I am Kundera Developer. where did you read **compliant means "supporting all the features"**? Kundera saves users' time. Check it's [home page](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera), I guess you can clearly see number of Stargazers, watchers, etc.

Comment: @devツ Why don't you state CLEARLY on your projects website the features that are supported and those that aren't then the user can easily see whether their project will be totally portable to other jPA vendors? Why don't you tell your users why you haven't done that?

Comment: Good point Billy. we can add supported features list in the project wiki.

Comment: @devツthat would be a great addition